# does checkinstall uninstall previously installed software?

Tags: software-installation, make, checkinstall

Originally I installed emacs 24.4 by compiling its source and checkinstall. I use the default install dir `--prefix=/usr/local`. So `/usr/local/bin/emacs`.

Now I use the same way to install emacs 24.5. This time I install it with `--prefix=/usr`. After running checkinstall, I thought I would need to manually uninstall 24.4, but I found `/usr/local/bin/emacs` is gone, and `dpkg -l | grep emacs` only shows 24.5.  Does that mean that `checkintall` uninstalls earlier installed version and then install the current version?
so I don't have to manually uninstall the earlier version?

If I install 24.5 by `make install` instead of `checkinstall`, will it also uninstall 24.4, or do I have to uninstall 24.4 manually (if yes, how?)?

If I installed 24.4 by `make install` instead of `checkinstall`, will now checkinstall 24.5 also uninstall 24.4, or do I have to uninstall 24.4 manually (if yes, how?)?

If I installed 24.4 and 24.5 by `make install` instead of `checkinstall`, will make install 24.5 also uninstall 24.4, or do I have to uninstall 24.4 manually (if yes, how?)?